# How can i add if statement in adobe flash?

Tags: flash, if-statement, adobe, conditional-statements

I want to have a counter and this counter increase in some case and then i need to check it with if statement. How can i do this? 
I mean there are two options and one of these option will increase the counter but other will not. If the counter reach a value which is identified by me then i want flash to stop.
Adobe CS6

Comment: Could you tell us what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

If statement in AS3 is very simple. It's full version is like:

```
If(<condition>) {
   <action>
} else if (<other condition>) {
   <other action>
} else {
  <another action>
}
```

The simpliest variant of "if" don't include "else" or "else if" statements.

```
If(<condition>) {
   <action>
}
```

In your case you have to make a special function and to call it every time, you want your counter to be modified. Like this:

```
function increaseCounter():void {
    counter++;
    if(counter >= someVal) {
        //your pause function
    }
}
```

P.S. Did I understand your question correctly? If I'd not, write a comment.